# How do I append results of for loop to table?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I have an array:

```
let items = document.getElementsByClassName('class-name')

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++ ) {
    status = items[i].innerText;
    console.log(status)
}
```

This returns either "SOLD" or "" depending on whether the item has been sold or not (it's an e-commerce page I'm looking at).

How do I append these results to a table?

I need a table with each item and whether it's been sold or not.

Answer (score 2):

this way

```js
const myTable = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('table'))

document.querySelectorAll('.class-name').forEach( status => {
  let newRow = myTable.insertRow()
  newRow.insertCell().textContent = status.textContent
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a `table` object via `document.createElement('table')` then create a new table row for each element via `document.createElement('tr')` after that you can "fill out" the `tr` and append it to the `table` via `element.appendChild(childToAppend)`. You can also append `td` elements to the `tr`.

Comment: Sorry...meant to write createElement....edited it now

Comment: @MisterJojo's answer is better. Using insertCell and insertRow looks much cleaner